# Problem when remove allobjects used with nsmutablearray

Tags: xcode, nsarray

```
    aryDesc = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; 
    NSMutableArray *ary_Temp ;
ary_Temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init ];
[ary_Temp addObject:@"Collins Burns"];
[ary_Temp addObject:@"cburns"];
[ary_Temp addObject:@"Active"];


    [aryDescListing addObject:ary_Temp];
[ary_Temp removeAllObjects];


[ary_Temp addObject:@"Collins Burns"];
[ary_Temp addObject:@"cburns"];
[ary_Temp addObject:@"Active"];


[aryDescListing addObject:ary_Temp];
    [ary_Temp removeAllObjects];

    NSLog(@"ary Description===== >>>%@",aryDescListing);
```

My code is as above i do get two objects in log but both are empty i dont know wheather to use remove all objects or to dealloc for ary_Temp .Should  i use  removeAllobjects or alloc it everytime after i add it to  aryDescListing.

Thanks

Comment: removeAllObjects does not release the array itself, whether NSLog(@"%@",ary_Temp) working correctly before and after the removeAllobject..

Comment: I have executed your code.But I am getting the output like this  ary Description===== >>>(
        (
        "Collins Burns",
        cburns,
        Active
    ),
        (
        "Collins Burns",
        cburns,
        Active
    )
)

Comment: remove allobjects means it removes only objects,this is not releasing the objects.If you want to release the objects means use the release whereever you want.

Comment: @arnold I am getting two object in aryDescListing and both are empty.

Comment: please create a new project and paste your code whatever you have asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `dealloc`, instead use `release`. `dealloc` will deallocate the object without taking in count the retain count of it and it will break your app sooner or later.

Perhaps you want this? :

```
aryDesc = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
NSMutableArray *ary_Temp ;

ary_Temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[ary_Temp addObject:@"Collins Burns"];
[ary_Temp addObject:@"cburns"];
[ary_Temp addObject:@"Active"];
[aryDescListing addObject:ary_Temp];
[ary_Temp release];

ary_Temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[ary_Temp addObject:@"Collins Burns"];
[ary_Temp addObject:@"cburns"];
[ary_Temp addObject:@"Active"];
[aryDescListing addObject:ary_Temp];
[ary_Temp release];

NSLog(@"ary Description===== >>>%@",aryDescListing);
```

BTW: `removeAllObject` will remove the objects from the array (and will decrease their `retainCount` by one)  but not will release the array.

Comment: is allocating and releasing array multiple times say for atleast hunderads of time is really good from programming point of view .Thanks for your inputs, is there other way to do this ..

Comment: what exactly you want to do? have an array with 6 objects? an array of arrays? an array of two arrays only? That answer was a guess since I what you wan't is not really clear in my opinion.

Comment: @mugen your question sounds like premature optimization.  Unless you have a specific, quantified, performance problem, then you shouldn't be concerned.

Comment: @mugen From a programming point of view the most clear and understandable code is best.  Then profile to find the real hot spots that need optimization.